# SendInput won't execute correctly via Java Native Access for mouse movement

Tags: java, c++, jna, sendinput

#### Intent

I am trying to create a localized implementation of cloud gaming where a user's own PC serves as the server. What I am trying to achieve is the last piece stopping me. That is implementing hardware mouse movements. This is where Windows' `SendInput()` comes into play.

#### Issue

The issue I have right now is that My entire code is based on Kotlin/Java. So, I don't exactly know how to replicate the functions of `SendInput()` in Java other than to use JNA to access C++ functions. More specifically access `SendInput()`. But, here's where I'm stuck. My Java code compiles, but doesn't execute when called.

#### Code to be translated to Java

```cpp
#include<windows.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void moveMouse(int x, int y) {
    INPUT input;
    input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
    input.mi.dx = x;
    input.mi.dy = y;
    input.mi.time = 0;
    input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
    UINT qwe = SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
    cout<< qwe;
}
```

#### Code in Java using JNA

look into the comments in the code below.

```java
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.DWORD;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LONG;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.INPUT;

//import static com.sun.jna.Native.sizeof;//compilation error 'sizeof(int)' has private access in 'com.sun.jna.Native'
import static com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.INPUT.INPUT_MOUSE;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        moveMouse(
                1_000L,
                1_000L
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param x change required in x co-ordinate
     * @param y change required in y co-ordinate
     *
     */
    public static void moveMouse(Long x, Long y) {
        INPUT input = new INPUT();
        input.type = new DWORD(INPUT_MOUSE);
        input.input.mi.dx = new LONG(x);
        input.input.mi.dy = new LONG(y);
        input.input.mi.time = new DWORD(0);
        input.input.mi.dwFlags = new DWORD(0x0001L);

        INPUT[] inputArray = {input};

        DWORD result = User32.INSTANCE.SendInput(new DWORD(1), inputArray, input.size());

        // sizeof (used below in the commented code) returns the compilation error
        // 'sizeof(int)' has private access in 'com.sun.jna.Native'
        // I got the idea to use sizeof from another StackOverflow post
//        DWORD result = User32.INSTANCE.SendInput(new DWORD(1), inputArray, sizeof(input));
        System.out.println("result = " + result.longValue());
        System.out.println("size = " + input.size());
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
result = 1
size = 40
```

You'll see that in `SendInput`, I'm sending the size of the input variable instead of the array's size which is what I'm supposed to send. To get the size of array in bytes, I got the idea to use `sizeof`, but, as you have seen above in the comments, you'll have already understood why I can't use it as I can't import a private function.

The mouse doesn't move a pixel when the Java code is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to net type. Didn't realize this was necessary. Anyways, here is the code -

```
public static void moveMouse(Long x, Long y) {
    INPUT input = new INPUT();
    input.type = new DWORD(INPUT_MOUSE);
    input.input.setType("mi");//--------------------------------------added this
    input.input.mi.dx = new LONG(x);
    input.input.mi.dy = new LONG(y);
    input.input.mi.time = new DWORD(0);
    input.input.mi.dwFlags = new DWORD(0x0001L);
    INPUT[] inputArray = {input};
    DWORD result = User32.INSTANCE.SendInput(new DWORD(1), inputArray, input.size());
}
```

For anybody having this issue, this function can be straight up copy pasted and it should work.